# Convert List<string> containing many-to-many relationship items into one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, list, lambda, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a List that contains strings which are delimited by a ' ' The list serves to function as a list of many to many relationships:

```
Category1 Item1
Category1 Item2
Category1 Item3
Category2 Item1 
Category2 Item2 
Category2 Item3
Category2 Item4
Category2 Item5
Category3 Item1
```

I need to convert this list into one which has a one to many relationship order, with the items separated by a ';' example:

```
Category1 Item1;Item2;Item3
Category2 Item1;Item2;Item3;Item4;Item5
Category3 Item1
```

I have multiple foreach loops right now. I would love to share with you the many methods I've tried but it's truly a mess. However, something tells me there might be a Lambda technique to achieve this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting the resulting list to still be a list of strings?

Comment: Yes sir, exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items = new List<string> {
   "Category1 Item1",
   "Category1 Item2",
   "Category1 Item3",
   "Category2 Item1",
   "Category2 Item2",
   "Category2 Item3",
   "Category2 Item4",
   "Category2 Item5",
   "Category3 Item1"
};

var result = items.Select(x => x.Split(' '))
                  .Select(x => new {
                     Category = x[0],
                     Item = x[1]
                  })
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Category, y => y.Item, (k, e) => string.Join(";", e))
                  .ToList();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank yo for this, I get some errors:

(k, e) => string.Join(';', e)

Error CS0136 A local or parameter named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter 
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string' 
Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'

Comment: I replaced e with d and changed single quotes to double for the semicolon delimiter. Also, I inserted a ' ' (single space) into the x.Split method. I can confirm all works!!! Thanks. If you update your code in the answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Not sure what happened why I copied, but I have now made changes. The error related to 'e cannot be declared' must be because you have 'e' already defined in your code and is conflicting with the 'e' I am using. Anyways, glad it helped.

Comment: bwt, string.split does not need an explit empty space since default behavior is "If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters." -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The category was missing from the list item (I guess I was not clear about the requirement), so I modified this line, as follows:
.GroupBy(x => x.Category, y => y.Item, (k, d) => k + "|" + string.Join(";", d))